# What is the definitive way to install/upgrade/set the default version of ZSH?

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh, osx-mountain-lion

OSX Mountain Lion ships with ZSH 4.3.1 in /bin/zsh. After downloading, `./configure, make, make check,` and `make install`-ing version 5.0.0,

`which zsh` still returns `/bin/zsh/`

and `zsh --version` still returns `zsh 4.3.11 (i386-apple-darwin12.0)`

**Items of note to help answerers:**
I had no errors running the install commands.

In `/usr/local/bin`, I have these 3 files:
`-rwxr-xr-x   2 kevinsuttle  admin   622K Aug 20 00:59 zsh`
`-rwxr-xr-x   2 kevinsuttle  admin   622K Aug 20 00:59 zsh-5.0.0`
`-rwxr-xr-x   1 kevinsuttle  admin   622K Aug 20 00:50 zsh.old`

**My `$PATH`**
`$ echo $PATH`
`/Users/kevinsuttle/.rbenv/shims:/Users/kevinsuttle/.rbenv/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin`

**Questions I need answered**:
1. What is the cleanest way to install ZSH? (From git, homebrew, curl-ing source?)
2. Does it matter where you run the install commands?
3. How do I upgrade or override the version of ZSH that ships with Mountain Lion?
4. Is this why people end up using [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh)?

Comment: I'm not sure how this will affect things, but you could point your local shell to the version you want? Create a symlink in your own `~/bin`, add that early enough in your `PATH`.

Comment: This led me to the solution indirectly. I just had to add the directory of the one I wanted to my $PATH. Thanks!

Answer (score 49):

You have to set your default shell in OSX with:

```
chsh -s /usr/local/bin/zsh $USER
```

Relogin to OSX and it should work!

## Homebrew way

I recommand you to use homebrew. It makes things much easier.
Install homebrew, like described on [Link](https://brew.sh/) .

Homebrew installs your stuff in /usr/local/bin, so make sure /usr/local/bin comes before /usr/bin .

Add the following line in ~/.zshrc and ~/.bashrc :

```
PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"
```

Install zsh:

```
brew install zsh
```

Set your default shell to zsh:

```
chsh -s /usr/local/bin/zsh $USER
```

Finally set permission to use zsh from brew installation. Add "/usr/local/bin/zsh" to "/etc/shells" file to allow zsh. Else you'll get an error "You are not authorized to run this application. The administrator has set your shell to an illegal value."

```
echo "/usr/local/bin/zsh" | sudo tee -a /etc/shells
```

I recommand to fix the zsh environment bug in OSX. Rename /etc/zshenv to /etc/zshrc

```
sudo mv /etc/{zshenv,zshrc}
```

Relogin to OSX and it should work!

If you have trouble, type:

```
brew doctor
```

Comment: Just wanted to toss in that on a Mac the 'official' way to change a user's default shell is by right clicking your name in the accounts panel in System Preferences (with 'make changes' unlocked) and change the default shell under advanced options. I'm not sure whether that is literally identical to using chsh.

Comment: I don't think it is necessary to mess with the $PATH order, for the reason you specified, since you are using `chsh -s` to use the shell located at `/usr/local/bin/zsh`. What the $PATH will determine is which version of `zsh` runs when you invoke it to run a script, or run `zsh` or something. Also note that OS X's `zsh` lives in `/bin/` not `/usr/bin/`.

Comment: Actually, before you can change the shell you need to add `/usr/local/bin/zsh` to `/etc/shells` so that it can be selected by `chsh`.

Comment: Great answer. Note typo: `chsh -s /user/local/bin/zsh $USER` should have `usr` instead of `user`

Comment: On MacBook Pro Catalina OS, just running `brew install zsh` worked for me. Afterwhich I ran `which zsh` and it returned `/usr/local/bin/zsh`

Answer (score 3):

OK, so Burhan's comment reminded me of a situation where I had to explicitly add the path of the preferred version to my `.bash_profile`. Version 5.0.0 is in `/usr/local/bin`, so now the `$PATH` in my `.bash_profile` looks like so:

`export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH"`

and now when I run `which zsh`, I get `/usr/local/bin/zsh`
and `zsh --version` returns `zsh 5.0.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin12.0.0)`.

Woot! Hopefully this helps someone who is having the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

I will attempt to answer your questions, but I have a feeling this is better suited for [superuser](http://superuser.com)

> What is the cleanest way to install ZSH? (From git, homebrew, curl-ing source?)

Acquiring the source however you want; but the cleanest way would be to create a private `bin`, I like `/Users/burhan/bin/`, and install things there. This is, in my opinion, the *cleanest* and *simplest* way since you don't need to rely on other libraries/installers/magic.

> Does it matter where you run the install commands?

No, it does matter what arguments you give the commands - especially the target installation location and path to libraries. If you don't provide these (or set them in the environment before hand), the installer will place items in the default system paths; and to do *that* you need to run the installer with elevated permissions ie, with `sudo` or while logged in as `root`.

> How do I upgrade or override the version of ZSH that ships with Mountain Lion?

I would recommend against upgrading it; simply because I am not sure what side effects it will have on the various other scripts that are expecting to it to ship with the advertised version. For your sanity, I would avoid this.

Instead, if you build and install it into a private bin and point your `PATH` appropriately; you can use the updated version without modifying the shipped version.

Comment: Hm, now I have to edit /etc/shells to get chsh to recognize the new location, which is fine, but I didn't have to do that on Lion. Also, once I change my default shell to zsh, the active process in the window title still reads bash. It's odd. I ran `chsh -s /usr/local/bin/zsh kevinsuttle` to change the default. 

`$ echo $0` returns `-bash` and `$ echo $SHELL` returns `/usr/local/bin/zsh`.

Comment: To fix that, edit `Terminal > Preferences` and then set the default startup shell; then in `Settings`, select your theme and click on the `Windows` tab; you can modify what title is shown there. I really like `iTerm2` for this because it is much more customizable.

Comment: Thanks Burhan. That did it. Still odd behavior from chsh though. I didn't have to do this little dance before. Must be why so many people give up and use oh-my-zsh for config.

Comment: I think this might be a `Terminal` specific thing Kevin. I stopped using it because of this and other "quirks". `iTerm2` or `Terminator` if you are going to be spending much of your time in the shell.

Answer (score 0):

In the past, the solution I came up with for this type of upgrade was roughly as follows:

- Install the newer version somewhere ( in my case the default for fink /sw/bin )
- Rename the OS-installed version in /bin /bin/zsh => /bin/zsh.moved
- Set up a symlink in /bin to the /sw/bin/zsh installation

This seemed to work.